# How to increase PHP PDO max buffer size when using mysqlnd?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using php 5.6 in a project, and employing `PDO` to access a remote mysql database (on AWS).

I am encountering the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

At first sight I though this would be easy to fix, by simply setting `MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` as an attribute to the `PDO` constructor, but it seems that value is not supported as `PDO` is compiled against `mysqlnd`

Can anyone tell me how to increase the buffer size in this case? I don't seem to find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems this can be solved by changing `max_allowed_packet` on the mysql server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This change is required in MySql config not in Php.

in `my.ini` or `my.cnf` add these lines,

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

To check the configuration you can do this :

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```